# Fairness of a coin that gives 50 heads from 163 trials

Tags: probability, statistics

You toss a coin 163 times and get 50 heads. Test the hypothesis that it is a fair coin, using a two-tailed test and 5% level of significance.

The answer wants each of the following: test statistic, critical value, and accept or reject the hypothesis.

It is quite obvious to me that we will reject the null hypothesis since the 2 z-scores associated with getting less than 50 tails (50.5 using continuity correction) are -4.86 and 4.86, while at a 5% confidence interval, the two z-scores are -1.96 and 1.96,  but I am not sure what he wants for the test statistic or critical value, or what those are exactly.

Comment: Hint: what distribution does the coin follow? The theorem you want to use afterward is *central* to your success.

Comment: normal? And wouldn't the critical value be 1.96 since thats where the 2nd deviation is?

Comment: binomial actually. I know how to calculate that probability, I'm just not sure what a test statistic or critical value is, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 50 heads out of 163 is a proportion, we should use the relevant one-sample $z$-test (we can do so since 163 is a large number):
$$z=\frac{(\hat p-p_0)\sqrt n}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)}}$$
Here
$$H_0:p=p_0=\frac12\quad H_1:p\ne\frac12$$
$$\hat p=\frac{50}{163}=0.307\quad n=163$$
so the test statistic is
$$z=\frac{(0.307-0.5)\sqrt{163}}{\sqrt{0.5×0.5}}=-4.928$$
The critical values are $\pm1.960$ as you thought. Since $-4.928$ falls outside $[-1.960,1.960]$, we reject the null hypothesis and conclude the coin is biased.

Comment: So the test statistic would be -4.928?

Comment: @JohnH Yes.${}$

Comment: Why isn't it 50-81.5/sqrt(163*.5*.5). They are close to each other, and both nearly impossible, but still.

Comment: Oh and just realized you said that that was the test statistic in your original answer, oops.

Comment: @JohnH We are testing a _proportion_ that is restricted to $[0,1]$ here, not a continuous value like 50 heads or 17 cars passing by. This difference is subtle and I learned it in my statistics class.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense.

Comment: You missed continuity correction.

Comment: @user371530 There is no continuity correction to be applied here. That only applies when calculating cdf values, not when conducting significance tests.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If I had to put one critical value, should I go with -1.96?

Comment: @JohnH Yes, go for $-1.96$.